# NetSuite Sales Teams and Groups

Tags: netsuite

Using Sales Force Automation in NetSuite, you can create Sales Teams (via Setup->Sales->Sales Teams->New). From what I can gather, these appear to be a kind of Group of employees (you can list them via a saved search). You can then use them to assign an entire Sales Team to a customer (which really means assigning all of the people in that Sales Team to the customer - NetSuite doesn't keep a record of which Sales Team you assigned, just its members).

We have multiple (hundreds) of sales teams defined. One for this state, one for that state, one for this group of counties in this other state, one for that state but just for customers who are under a certain threshold of revenue, etc., etc. So we get employees who are on multiple sales teams - again, some employees are on tens or hundreds of sales teams.

What I want to do is operate on those sales teams via a mass update or similar. For example, I want to be able to remove John Smith from all Sales Teams (I stress that by this I do not mean remove him from all customers in which he is in the sales team; I mean remove him from the defined Sales Team), or add Sue Brown to all Sales Teams involved in a specific state. Again, I stress that I don't mean to make changes to the people or sales teams assigned to customers - if I made this change, it would not change anything in relation to any customers; it would ONLY change the Sales Team itself.

But I can't even search for Sales Teams (or groups) and get the names of all the members in the search result.

How are Sales Teams structured/stored in NetSuite? Can they be operated on in this way?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have this feature enabled in my account, so I cannot see first hand.  However in Suite Answer I found [Answer Id 9772](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9772) that explains how to perform a Mass Update of sales team members, i.e. to add or remove an individual from a Sales Team and the different mass update types.

Comment: Thanks, Martha - but that's not what I need. That's to do with mass updating sales teams that have been assigned to a customer. For example, if I know that John Smith has been assigned to a hundred customers, I can use a mass update to remove him from those customers. See my continued comment below...

Comment: But with SFA, you can create an entity called a Sales Team, and that entity contains a number of people. You can then assign the Sales Team to a customer. I want to change the members of the Sales Team. That won't affect any customers to which the Sales Team has already been assigned, but it means that next time I assign the Sales Team to a customer, it'll get the changed Sales Team. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, I see.  When looking at a "Sales Team" in NetSuite what's the intneralid/NetSuite technical record name/type?  (Look at the url, typically before ".nl?").  We can check that literal internalid in their Records Browser amongst other places to see what's possible.

Comment: When I go to Setup->Sales->Sales teams I get a list of all Sales Teams at the URL https://XXXXXXXX.app.netsuite.com/app/crm/common/salesteamlist.nl?whence=

When I open a particular Sales Team, I get that team's form at the URL https://XXXXXXXX.app.netsuite.com/app/crm/common/crmgroup.nl?id=10186922

Comment: Per the 2021.1 Records Browser (https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/script/record/entitygroup.html) and Suite answer 10242 (https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10242), neither "salesteamlist" or "crmgroup" are supported by SuiteScript. The other option(s) could be an offering within SuiteTalk REST or SOAP Web Services.   I admittedly do not know enough about these offerings, but you can reference suite Answer 87496 (https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/87496).